# Transform a sequence using the fewest number of steps possible

Tags: python, algorithm, levenshtein-distance, constraint-programming, register-allocation

My question is, what algorithm should I use to implement a function
`translate` that works according to the following Python examples:

```
>>> translate('aa', 'a')
[('S', -1)]
>>> translate('a', 'aa')
[('R', 0, 'x'), ('S', 1), ('W', 0, 'x')]
>>> translate('abc', bca')
[('R', 0, 'x'), ('R', 1, 'y'), ('R', 2, 'z'),
 ('W', 2, 'x'), ('W', 0, 'y'), ('W', 1, 'z')]
>>> translate('abc', 'cabc')
[('R', 2, 'x'), ('S', 1), ('W', 0, 'x')]
>>> translate('ab', 'bab')
[('R', 1, 'x'), ('S', 1), ('W', 0, 'x')]
>>> translate('abc', 'bcabc')
[('R', 1, 'x'), ('R', 2, 'y'), ('S', 2), ('W', 0, 'x'), ('W', 1, 'y')]
```

It's a generalization of a problem related to generating optimal code
in a compiler that I'm having. The algorithm is what I'm after so the
solution does not necessarily have to be in Python. In "reality" the
variables (`'x'`, `'y'` and `'z'` in the above) are machine registers
and the string indices stack locations.

As you can see from the example, the algorithm is about transforming a
string from one sequence of characters to another using the fewest
number of steps. With the caveat that there are only three possible
operations to choose from:

1. Shift the string to the left or right N number of steps. If it's
   shifted to the right, the new indices introduced are filled with
   `?` characters. E.g `('S', 2)` -- shift the string two indices to
   the right.
2. Read character at index into a variable. This operation cant be
   performed if there are any `?` characters in the string. E.g
   `('R', 4, 'q')` -- read the character at index 4 and store it in the
   variable `q`.
3. Write character from variable into index at destination string. The
   index must be within bounds. E.g `('W', 1, 'q')` -- write the character in
   the variable `q` at index 0 in the string.

Here is trivial Python code to implement those operations and an
example of how the transformation from `ab` to `bab` would be
performed manually:

```
def shift(str, n): return str[-n:] if n < 0 else '?'*n + str
def read(str, n): assert not '?' in str; return str[n]
def write(str, n, ch): return str[:n] + ch + str[n:]

S = 'ab'
x = read(S, 1)
S = shift(S, 1)
S = write(S, 0, x)
```

This sequence of steps would correspond to the solution
`[('R', 1, 'x'), ('S', 1), ('W', 0, 'x')]`.

I have a feeling there is some similary between this problem av
levenshtein editing distance, but I can't figure it out. So can *you*
write the `translate` algorithm for me?

I'll add more examples if this problem description isn't clear enough
but I hope it is.

Comment: You need to create the dynamic programming matrix, fill it, and then backtrack from the bottom right to the top left to retrace the steps that you need.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I think I fixed your Python code. Here's a class that can run a sequence of steps and give the result. Your example left a `?` in the result, which I think wasn't supposed to happen.

Here's the `SequenceRunner`

```
class SequenceRunner:

    def __init__(self):
        self.INSTRUCTIONS = {
            'R': self.read,
            'S': self.shift,
            'W': self.write
            }

    def set(self, S):
        self.S = S[::-1]

    def shift(self, n):
        self.S = self.S[-n:] if n < 0 else  '?'*n + self.S

    def read(self, n, v):
        assert not '?' in self.S; return self.S[n]

    def write(self, n, v):
        v = getattr(self, v)
        self.S = self.S[:n] + v + self.S[n+1:]

    def run(self, program):
        for line in program:
            func = self.INSTRUCTIONS[line[0]]
            args = line[1:]
            result = func(*args)
            if result:
                setattr(self, args[-1], result)

    def get(self):
        return self.S[::-1]
```

And here's how to use it

```
c = SequenceRunner()
program = [('R', 1, 'x'), ('S', 1), ('W', 0, 'x')]
c.set('ab')
c.run(program)
print c.get()
```

**Question so I understand better:** do you need an algorithm that can deduce the (least amount of) steps needed to go from one string to another?

Comment: Correct. Your solution takes the input string and the program and produces the output string. But I want to take the input string and the output string and produce the program.